# Inline edit is not working with a validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Hi friends we have so many validation rules are there in opportunity page.recently i had created a new validation rule like.

```
OR( 
AND(ISNEW(),ISPICKVAL( StageName ,"Closed Won"),ISPICKVAL( Reason_Won__c ,"")), 
AND(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > Date(2016,9,30), 
ISPICKVAL( StageName ,"Closed Won"),ISPICKVAL( Reason_Won__c ,"")) 
)
```

If opportunity has been created or editing the opportunity after created on a specific month.I throws an error.

Everything is working fine.But sometimes sales rep try to edit any specific field on opportunity through inline editing it throws an error.If the didn't meet the criteria.

I have no clue why it happens like this.

Comment: Please confirm if you get always error when you do Inline Edit.

Comment: Randomly it throws an error.Like there is an opportunity with stage is prospecting.When he try to update other field through inline edit throws an error.But when he try's to update the same opportunity through edit it's working fine.@TusharSharma